# Variable on External JAR not being updated

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So I built a JAR (A.jar) that uses an external JAR library (B.jar)

Inside B.jar theres only 1 variable

```
private static final byte myByte = 1;
```

And I run A.jar main class in a separate computer with a different Java VM like this:

```
java -classpath A.jar;B.jar; main
```

The problem is, when I release a new version of B.jar with myByte = 2, A.jar still reads myByte as 1 and not 2.

I already made sure that the old and new B library was not compiled/included inside A.jar.

Why is A.jar not using B.jar external reference? But its using like a cache version of the old B.jar?

Comment: If you export the jar from eclipse, try exporting it in a different folder, maybe Eclipse is getting confused and releases a cached version, try also a project clean first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't automatically rescan the contents of external jar files on Java Build Paths--they don't just change contents yet remain in the same location with the same jar name most of the time. Try removing the jar from the Java Build Path, exiting the Properties dialog, and then adding it back.

Comment: I mean, when I run the jar on a Java VM, it still shows the old value and not the new one. Sorry I didn't make it clear on my question

Comment: It's possible the old value was inlined.wherever you've used in in A.